# Neigbourhoods in Large Neighbourhood Search (LNS) algorithms

Tags: heuristics, algorithms, graphs, traveling-salesman

I have been trying to implement a variant of LNS on a graph for TSP. One of the ways that I can define a neighborhood for TSP is to find $k$-shortest path between two nodes. But the choice of these nodes are random. I have two questions:

1. Are there better ways to define neighborhood?
2. Is there a way to find a promising neighborhood?

Comment: This paper is particularly useful when working on (A)LNS, and provides great guidance and an overview of operators/neighborhoods. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305054805003023

Comment: @AlbertSchrotenboer that seems like it deserves to be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305054805003023) paper by Pisinger and Ropke is particularly useful when working on (A)LNS, and provides great guidance and an overview of operators/neighborhoods. I would suggest [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037722171300800X) by Vidal et al. for more genetic search inspired aspects.

Answer (score 8):

These common neighborhoods for TSP/VRP might be useful:

- 2-opt, 3-opt, ..., k-opt
- change 1 visit: remove 1 visit from a chain and insert it somewhere else in a chain
- swap 2 visits
- change a subchain of visits: remove a number of sequential visits from a chain and insert it somewhere else in a chain, sometimes reversed
- swap 2 subchains
- ruin&recreate